# Hydrated Bloc - Data isn't persist when the app is restarted and there is no internet connection

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dictionary, bloc

I am making an application and i want to persist the data so that when the app is restarted and eventhough there is no internet connection, the old data will still be there and shown in the UI. My other hydrated_bloc works just fine but only this hydrated_bloc doesnt seems to be working.

Firstly, this is my StatusVerificationModel()

```
class StatusVerificationModel extends Equatable {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> statusList;

  const StatusVerificationModel({required this.statusList});

  factory StatusVerificationModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> status = [];

    if(map['status'] != "") {
      status = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(map['status'])
          .map((statusItem) => {
            "id": statusItem['id'] ?? "",
            "editable": statusItem['editable'] ?? "",
            "status": statusItem['status'] ?? "",
            "date_created": statusItem['date_created'],
            "name": statusItem['name'],
            "start_date": statusItem['start_date'] ?? "",
            "end_date": statusItem['end_date'] ?? "",
            "start_time": statusItem['start_time'] ?? "",
            "end_time": statusItem['end_time'] ?? "",
            "justification": statusItem['justification'] ?? "",
            "reasons": statusItem['reasons'] ?? "",
            "fileNames": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_names']),
            "filePaths": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_paths']),
          })
      .toList();
    }

    return StatusVerificationModel(
      statusList: status,
    );
  }

  factory StatusVerificationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> status = [];

    if(json['status'] != "") {
      status = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json['status'])
          .map((statusItem) => {
            "id": statusItem['id'] ?? "",
            "editable": statusItem['editable'] ?? "",
            "status": statusItem['status'] ?? "",
            "date_created": statusItem['date_created'],
            "name": statusItem['name'],
            "start_date": statusItem['start_date'] ?? "",
            "end_date": statusItem['end_date'] ?? "",
            "start_time": statusItem['start_time'] ?? "",
            "end_time": statusItem['end_time'] ?? "",
            "justification": statusItem['justification'] ?? "",
            "reasons": statusItem['reasons'] ?? "",
            "fileNames": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_names']),
            "filePaths": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_paths']),
          })
      .toList();
    }

    return StatusVerificationModel(
      statusList: status,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "status": statusList,
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "status": statusList,
    };
  }
}
```

and this is my AttendanceStatusState()

```
abstract class AttendanceStatusState extends Equatable {
  const AttendanceStatusState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AttendanceStatusInitial extends AttendanceStatusState {}

class AttendanceStatusLoading extends AttendanceStatusState {}

class AttendanceStatusLoaded extends AttendanceStatusState {
  final StatusVerificationModel? attendanceStatus;
  final StatusVerificationModel? attendanceVerification;

  const AttendanceStatusLoaded({this.attendanceStatus, this.attendanceVerification});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "attendanceStatus": attendanceStatus?.toMap(),
      "attendanceVerification": attendanceVerification?.toMap(),
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "attendanceStatus": attendanceStatus?.toJson(),
      "attendanceVerification": attendanceVerification?.toJson(),
    };
  }

  factory AttendanceStatusLoaded.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return AttendanceStatusLoaded(
      attendanceStatus: StatusVerificationModel.fromJson(map['attendanceStatus']),
      attendanceVerification: StatusVerificationModel.fromJson(map['attendanceVerification']),
    );
  }

  factory AttendanceStatusLoaded.fromJson(String source) =>
      AttendanceStatusLoaded.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

and lastly this is AttendanceStatusCubit()

```
class AttendanceStatusCubit extends HydratedCubit<AttendanceStatusState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  final AttendanceStatusRepository _attendanceStatusRepository;

  StatusVerificationModel? lastLoadedAttendanceStatus;
  StatusVerificationModel? lastLoadedAttendanceVerification;

  AttendanceStatusCubit({required UserRepository userRepository, required AttendanceStatusRepository attendanceStatusRepository})
      : _userRepository = userRepository, _attendanceStatusRepository = attendanceStatusRepository,
        super(AttendanceStatusInitial()) {
    AttendanceStatusInitialized();
  }

  void AttendanceStatusInitialized() async {
    emit(AttendanceStatusLoading());

    var user = await _userRepository.getUser();

    if(user != null) {
      try {
        var attendanceStatus = await _attendanceStatusRepository.getData(id: user.id);
        var attendanceVerification = await _attendanceStatusRepository.getVerificationData(id: user.id);
        lastLoadedAttendanceStatus = attendanceStatus;
        lastLoadedAttendanceVerification = attendanceVerification;
        emit(AttendanceStatusLoaded(attendanceStatus: attendanceStatus, attendanceVerification: attendanceVerification));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(const AttendanceStatusError(error: "Error: No Internet Connection"));
        emit(AttendanceStatusLoaded(attendanceStatus: lastLoadedAttendanceStatus, attendanceVerification: lastLoadedAttendanceVerification));
      }
    } else {
      emit(const AttendanceStatusEmpty(message: "Session ended, please login to continue"));
    }
  }
 @override
  AttendanceStatusState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return AttendanceStatusLoaded.fromMap(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(AttendanceStatusState state) {
    if(state is AttendanceStatusLoaded) {
      lastLoadedAttendanceVerification = state.attendanceVerification;
      lastLoadedAttendanceStatus = state.attendanceStatus;

      return state.toMap();
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

and this is the prompt when i restarted the app
`I/flutter (14491): AttendanceStatusCubit type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building BlocBuilder<AttendanceStatusCubit, AttendanceStatusState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AttendanceStatusCubit?>], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<AttendanceStatusCubit, AttendanceStatusState>#06944):
The getter 'statusList' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: statusList

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BlocBuilder<AttendanceStatusCubit, AttendanceStatusState> BlocBuilder:file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Android%20Studio/HPCS/KPM/KPM/lib/screens/pages/status_verification.dart:53:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      _StatusVerificationState._createDataTable (package:kpm_scanme/screens/pages/status_verification.dart:230:34)
#2      _StatusVerificationState.paginatedDataTable (package:kpm_scanme/screens/pages/status_verification.dart:216:13)
#3      _StatusVerificationState.mainContent (package:kpm_scanme/screens/pages/status_verification.dart:131:11)
#4      _StatusVerificationState.mainUI (package:kpm_scanme/screens/pages/status_verification.dart:81:15)
#5      _StatusVerificationState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:kpm_scanme/screens/pages/status_verification.dart:60:26)
#6      BlocBuilder.build (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:90:57)
```

May i know what is the problem? Been trying to change many things but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally able to find the reason. It was not the hydrated_bloc parts that i got it wrong. But the null check is the reason it doesn't work.

```
I/flutter (14491): AttendanceStatusCubit type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

this part is the main reason for the problem and i found out that inside my StatusVerificationModel

```
if(map['status'] != "") {
  status = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(map['status'])
      .map((statusItem) => {
        "id": statusItem['id'] ?? "",
        "editable": statusItem['editable'] ?? "",
        "status": statusItem['status'] ?? "",
        "date_created": statusItem['date_created'],
        "name": statusItem['name'],
        "start_date": statusItem['start_date'] ?? "",
        "end_date": statusItem['end_date'] ?? "",
        "start_time": statusItem['start_time'] ?? "",
        "end_time": statusItem['end_time'] ?? "",
        "justification": statusItem['justification'] ?? "",
        "reasons": statusItem['reasons'] ?? "",
        "fileNames": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_names']),
        "filePaths": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_paths']),
      })
  .toList();
}
```

the errors are on

```
"fileNames": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_names']),
"filePaths": List<String>.from(statusItem['file_paths']),
```

I needed to add null check on that part so that there won't be any error. This is my updated code for it:

```
 "fileNames": statusItem['file_names'] != null
            ? List<String>.from(statusItem['file_names'])
            : [],
 "filePaths": statusItem['file_paths'] != null
            ? List<String>.from(statusItem['file_paths'])
            : [],
```